# How can I filter data and sum by name of one excel table from other excel table using VBA and R1C1 reference

Tags: excel, vba

I got stuck at a problem with Excel VBA. I want to sum the total sales of each person of the second table in excel. I am using VBA R1C1 reference.
Here is my data:

| Cookie Sales |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Month | February |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  | Year | 2022 |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Seller | Buyer | Cookie | Quantity | Cost | Sales |  |  | Monthly Sales |
| Charlie | Sally | Choco Chip | 7 | $ 5.00 | $ 35.00 |  | Charlie |  |
| Ella | Jimmy | Nutty Butter | 2 | $ 3.50 | $ 7.00 |  | Dana |  |
| Max | Veronica | Choco Chip | 3 | $ 5.00 | $ 15.00 |  | Ella |  |
| Dana | Leila | Snicky Doodles | 4 | $ 4.00 | $ 16.00 |  | Ezra |  |
| Ezra | Jimmy | Nutty Butter | 11 | $ 3.50 | $ 38.50 |  | Max |  |
| Charlie | Leila | Snicky Doodles | 5 | $ 4.00 | $ 20.00 |  | TOTAL | 0 |
| Max | Tricia | Choco Chip | 4 | $ 5.00 | $ 20.00 |  |  |  |
| Ella | Leila | Nutty Butter | 1 | $ 3.50 | $ 3.50 |  |  | Total Boxes |
| Ella | Leila | Choco Chip | 1 | $ 5.00 | $ 5.00 |  | Choco Chip |  |
| Charlie | Sally | Nutty Butter | 2 | $ 3.50 | $ 7.00 |  | Nutty Butter |  |
| Max | Veronica | Choco Chip | 6 | $ 5.00 | $ 30.00 |  | Snicky Doodles |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

And Here I tried this code:

```
Range("H6").Offset(5, 0).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Range("A6").Offset(10, 6)
Range("I6").Offset(5, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[6]C[-4]:R[10]C[4])"
```

But this is not working. Now I need help to solve this problem.

Comment: Does it need to be VBA, this is what pivot tables are for.

Comment: It would be easier to help you, if you provide your sample data as text in your question (ideally using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) (read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16578424) for an explanation)) and not as a very small screenshot.

Comment: You can use as `SUMIFS`-formula to achieve this.

Comment: just looking at your code, first off, I think most of those `.Offset(#, #)` need to be changed to `.Resize(#, #)` . Is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Warcupine I am doing an assignment using VBA. That's why i need this.

Comment: So your task is to add formulas via VBA to the sheet. Or is your task to calculate the results via VBA?

Comment: @Ike task is calculate sales by name and total sales using VBA R1C1 style